# SQLite3 PHP "Update" -result of prepared query

Tags: php, sqlite, sql-update, prepared-statement

Does somebody know how i can check in PHP if an SQLite3 update query (prepared) was succesful or not?

Her my code...

```
$stmt = $project->prepare( 'UPDATE tasks set title=:title WHERE rowid=:rowid' );
$stmt->bindValue(':title', rtrim($_POST['title'],'<br>'), SQLITE3_TEXT);
$stmt->bindValue(':rowid', (int)$_POST['rel'], SQLITE3_INTEGER);
$result = $stmt->execute();
var_dump( $result );
```

This code is upodating my table. But "var_dump( $result )" return everytime an empty object. Even if i force an error by passing "rowid=non-existing-rowid".

Any ideas, how i can check my update query?

Answer (score 2):

An `UPDATE` statements updates as many record as match the `WHERE` condition; this could be zero, one, or many records.
On the SQL level, all of this is considered a success.

If you want to find out how many records were affected, you can use the [`changes` method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.changes.php) of the database connection object.
In your case:

```
...
$result = $stmt->execute();
if ($result) {
    echo 'Updated rows: ', $project->changes();
}
```